# drawing svg element in different container using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have 2 svg container and I want to draw different svg elements in both container. Let us suppose:

```
<div><svg height="100" width="100" id="svg1" class="svg"> </svg></div>
<div><svg height="100" width="100" id="svg2" class="svg"> </svg></div>
```

Now suppose I want to draw a rectangle in 1st one and a line in 2nd one using id in javascript and snap.svg. How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Read the Getting Started and Documentation part on [snapsvg.io](http://snapsvg.io/) then it should be a simple task.

```
  var s1 = Snap("#svg1");
  s1.rect(50, 50, 50, 50);

  var s2 = Snap("#svg2");
  var line = s2.line(50, 50, 100, 100);
  line.attr({
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 5,
    strokeLinecap:"round"
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just little bit enhanced the reply of @ctron with a jsfiddle and some explanations.

```
var s1 = Snap("#svg1")
,   s2 = Snap("#svg2")
// Create rect and save in a variable
,   rect = s1.rect(50, 50, 50, 50)
// Create line and save in a variable
,   line = s2.line(50, 50, 100, 100);

rect.attr({fill:"red"})

line.attr({
     stroke: "#0f0",
     strokeWidth: 5,
     strokeLinecap:"round"
  });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Leonardonline/8x27m6x6/)